# Internal / external link widget for Plone

Tags: plone

Does there exist anything akin "link widget" which would provide similar functionality as TinyMCE's link browser

- Browser site content and link internal links by a reference
- Link external links by copy-pasting full URL

In such thing does not exist, what would be a good starting point for link transformations? E.g. a reference browser which transforms the result to UID based link and then human readable link in the HTML output.

Preferably z3c.form or zope.formlib solution to be used with portlets.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago we developed such kind of field and widget for Archetypes http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.referencedatagridfield

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately needs to be z3c.form.